# Meteor template elements lose style during (re)render

Tags: meteor

I have a template that has a some text updated reactively once every second.

I also have a button, that when clicked, gets it's style changed to display a disabled button - this works fine but as soon as the template re-renders due to the condition above then the button reverts back to it's original style. It is almost as if the entire template is rendering from scratch (template.render is fired every second).

Is this normal? do I need to control the style via a reactive {{btnstyle}} type mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the typical way to do this is to set the style via a `class` that is set by a template helper function. For disabling button/input elements, you can just use the `disabled` attribute instead of `class`:

```html
<button type="button" {{#if buttonDisabled}}disabled{{/if}}>Button Text</button>
```

or

```html
<input type="button" value="Button Text" {{#if buttonDisabled}}disabled{{/if}} />
```

and then do:

```js
Template.yourFormTemplate.buttonDisabled = function() {
  // return true or false depending on if the button should be disabled
};
```

The problem is that when Meteor re-renders your template, the element which you set the style of is actually getting replaced with a new one. Note that the Meteor team is currently working on a new templating engine that works on a more fine-grained level, so that elements don't necessarily get replaced like that. You can try your current code with the preview release of the new templating engine with this command:

```
meteor --release shark-1-29-2014-e
```

or

```
mrt --release shark-1-29-2014-e
```

However, it is still generally recommended to style elements via the `class` attribute, set with a template helper. This is a more declarative, template-driven approach that just fits better with the "Meteor way" to do things, rather than the imperative approach of setting the style directly from your JavaScript. It also helps with separating concerns, by allowing your CSS to control the actual style.

Comment: Thanks - so it's actually correct that template.render is firing every time a reactive change occurs? An interesting note is that if I set the '.value' value then it does not get overridden by the template re-render.

Comment: Yes, that's how the old template engine is able to make the changes reflect in the HTML output. The new template engine is much smarter, being able to replace individual elements or just set their attributes individually. For this reason, `{{#constant}}`, `{{#isolate}}`, and `preserve` will no longer be needed, as they were an old workaround for preventing Meteor from re-rendering part of a template.

Comment: Here are the relevant parts of the Meteor Docs that help explain why the old templating engine works as it does: http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve, http://docs.meteor.com/#constant and http://docs.meteor.com/#isolate . Again, all three of these features are not present in the new template engine because it's smart enough to no longer need them.

Comment: A final note on why the `value` isn't getting overridden, this is because of the default `preserve-inputs` package. I'm not completely sure why it only preserves when the `value` has actually been changed, but regardless the `preserve-inputs` package is another feature that will be obsolete when the new template engine is released.